# Raspberry Pi Touchscreen Chromium Gestures

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, touchscreen, swipe-gesture, dashing

I have a Raspberry Pi 3, running Raspian OS and connected to the official 7" Raspberry Pi touchscreen. The Pi is used to display a information dashboard, built using the Dashing framework. The dashboard is displayed in Chromium and made full screen using the F11 key.

As it stands, the dashboard Pi works well. However, I would like to utilise the touchscreen more. My thoughts are to display multiple Dashing dashboards within a single instance of Chromium, each dashboard being displayed in a different tab, and use touchscreen gestures to switch between them. Something like a 3-finger swipe to switch between Chromium tabs, and hence dashboards, would be ideal.

Any thoughts on how I can do this? A quick google shows very little to do with gestures with the Raspberry Pi touchscreen.

Mark

Comment: I am stuck with the same idea. Could you get it working?

Comment: In the end I used the crxMouse extension for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clean-crxmouse-gestures/mjidkpedjlfnanainpdfnedkdlacidla?hl=en It wasn't the prettiest extension but it did allow me to complete the job